# python sklearn get list of available hyper parameters for model

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am using python with sklearn, and would like to get a list of available hyper parameters for a model, how can this be done? Thanks

This needs to happen before I initialize the model, when I try to use

```
model.get_params()
```

I get this

```
TypeError: get_params() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should do it: `estimator.get_params()` where `estimator` is the name of your model.

To use it on a model you can do the following:

```
reg = RandomForestRegressor()
params = reg.get_params()
# do something...
reg.set_params(params)
reg.fit(X,  y)
```

**EDIT:**

To get the model hyperparameters before you instantiate the class:

```
import inspect
import sklearn

models = [sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor, sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression]

for m in models:
    hyperparams = inspect.getargspec(m.__init__).args
    print(hyperparams) # Do something with them here
```

The model hyperparameters are passed in to the constructor in `sklearn` so we can use the `inspect` model to see what constructor parameters are available, and thus the hyperparameters. You may need to filter out some arguments that aren't specific to the model such as `self` and `n_jobs`.

Comment: this is only working for initialized model, I need to know what are the available params that i can use when i initialize the model, hence it is not initialized in this stage.

Comment: I see, you have a couple of options in that case:


1. The sklearn documentation but I'm guessing you want to do this programmatically


2. You can call `get_params()` on an uninitialized model, then initialize the model with `set_params()`. See my edited answer as the code won't format properly in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

As of **May 2021**:
(Building on sudo's answer)

```
# To get the model hyperparameters before you instantiate the class
import inspect
import sklearn

models = [sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression]
for m in models:
    hyperparams = inspect.signature(m.__init__)
    print(hyperparams)

#>>> (self, *, fit_intercept=True, normalize=False, copy_X=True, n_jobs=None)
```

Using `inspect.getargspec(m.__init__).args`, as suggested by sudo in the accepted answer, generated the following warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: inspect.getargspec() is deprecated since Python 3.0, 
use inspect.signature() or inspect.getfullargspec()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be looking at CatBoost, try `.get_all_params()` instead of `get_params()`.

Comment: From the error, it looks like the OP's issue is that they're calling an instance method on a class.

Answer (score 0):

`estimator._get_param_names()` will print out all available hyperparameters for a given estimator (model).

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

SVR._get_param_names()

['C',
 'cache_size',
 'coef0',
 'degree',
 'epsilon',
 'gamma',
 'kernel',
 'max_iter',
 'shrinking',
 'tol',
 'verbose']

RandomForestRegressor._get_param_names()

['bootstrap',
 'ccp_alpha',
 'criterion',
 'max_depth',
 'max_features',
 'max_leaf_nodes',
 'max_samples',
 'min_impurity_decrease',
 'min_samples_leaf',
 'min_samples_split',
 'min_weight_fraction_leaf',
 'n_estimators',
 'n_jobs',
 'oob_score',
 'random_state',
 'verbose',
 'warm_start']
```