# How to display all logistic regression hyperparameters in Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, hyperparameters

I imported the logistic regression class provided by Scikit-Learn and then created an object out of it:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
my_lr = LogisticRegression()
```

The book that I am studying says that when I examine my object I should see the following output:

```
LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multiclass='auto', n_jobs=None, penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver='warn', tool=0.0001, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```

However when I run my object in Jupyter Notebook I just see:

```
LogisticRegression()
```

Even when I write down all the hyperparameters by myself...

```
my_new_lr = LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multiclass='auto', n_jobs=None, penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver='warn', tool=0.0001, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```

... I just continue too see this kind output:

```
LogisticRegression(solver='warn')
```

This is disappointing because I would expect a lot of hyperparameters in the brackets, in order to see how their values are setted and become familiar with them.

Comment: Check this question [Similar Question] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54572468/python-sklearn-get-list-of-available-hyper-parameters-for-model )
And maybe the other reason is you are using default hyperparameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `model.get_params(deep=True)` method. So, this should give you the parameters set:

```
print(my_new_lr.get_params())
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `get_params` (which is worth knowing about for other reasons as well), there are at least two other ways to get some of this information.

In a Jupyter notebook, you can call `?LogisticRegression` to see the entire docstring (which is also what produces the API documentation pages), which details all the parameters.

Older versions of `sklearn` printed all the parameters by default when printing an estimator, hence your book's suggestion.  You can get that behavior back using the global configs, see [`set_config`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.set_config.html#sklearn.set_config) or [`config_context`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.config_context.html#sklearn.config_context).

Comment: You hit the nail on the head: the problem was that I'm using a newer version of `sklearn`. This is why I did not see the hyperparameters as I should.
Clarified this issue I think that I will use `?LogisticRegression` in order to easily get this info for my personal learn purposes.
Otherwise if I have to examine a certain specific model, of which I want to get more details, i will probably use the method `get_params()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pprint()` instead of `print()` for `model.get_params()`:

```py
from pprint import pprint

print('Parameters currently in use:\n')
pprint(my_new_lr.get_params())
```