# How to perform hyper-paramter tunning for SVC?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, hyperparameters

I am trying to perform hyper-parameter tuning of my model but this error keeps showing

```
error :  Invalid parameter svc_c for estimator SVC(). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()
```

I am using the following code :

```
param_grid = {'svc_c': [5, 10, 100], 
              'svc_gamma': [1,0.1,0.01,0.001],
              'svc_dgree': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
              'svc_kernel': ['rbf']}
grid = GridSearchCV(SVC(),param_grid,refit=True,verbose=3)
grid.fit(x_train_poly,y_train)
```

Comment: Please see the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html?highlight=svc#sklearn.svm.SVC) for the correct spelling of the hyperparameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the correct key for the dictionary `param_grid`.
`kernel` , `C` , `gamma` , `degree` and ... (see [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html))

try this:

```
param_grid = {'kernel': ('linear', 'rbf','poly') , 
              'C':[5, 10, 100],
              'gamma': [1,0.1,0.01,0.001], 
              'degree' : [1,2,3,4,5,6]}

grid = GridSearchCV(SVC() , param_grid , refit=True , verbose=3)
grid.fit(x_train_poly,y_train)
```

Comment: I did not run this, but I think it would be better to write `('rbf',)` because `('rbf')` may be interpreted as a list of characters (so try "r" and "b" and "f" as candidates) unless sklearn handles these somehow.

Comment: @KotaMori, I edit code, see answer, for set kernel we send `tuple`, see this link : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states, you are setting invalid parameter names for each hyper-parameter. In this [stackoverflow  question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54572468/python-sklearn-get-list-of-available-hyper-parameters-for-model), a way of showing a list of available hyper-parameters for a given estimator is shown. Then, I'd suggest you to change your code to this:

```
param_grid = {'C': [5, 10, 100], 
              'gamma': [1,0.1,0.01,0.001],
              'degree': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
              'kernel': ['rbf']}
```

Please, check if those hyper-parameters are actually included in the list that
`estimator.get_params().keys()` returns.