# How to display the fit method list of parameters?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

I'm taking a course (introduction to machine learning with python), and im using PyCharm for coding. One of the exercises im working on it is the "Iris example" with the KNeighborsClassifer.

```
In[26]:
knn.fit(X_train, y_train) 

Out[26]:
KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
       metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, n_neighbors=1, p=2,
       weights='uniform')***
```

the problem here is that I cannot get the same output( the list of parameters) for fit_method() when typing the syntax in [26]. I know that the book is using a different IDE than Pycharm but I get nothing when I run it. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit difficult to understand what the problem is but based on what I could gather, you are trying to display the parameters for the `fit()` function.

The sklearn fit function only takes X and y as input parameters `fit(X, y)`

where:

> X{array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features) or
> (n_samples, n_samples) if metric=’precomputed’* - Training Input Data
>
> y{array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples,
> n_outputs)* - Target Values

Check out the following snippet from the sklearn documentation for futher clarification:

```
>>> X = [[0], [1], [2], [3]]
>>> y = [0, 0, 1, 1]
>>> from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
>>> neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
>>> neigh.fit(X, y)
KNeighborsClassifier(...)
>>> print(neigh.predict([[1.1]]))
[0]
>>> print(neigh.predict_proba([[0.9]]))
[[0.666... 0.333...]]
```

Also, using `n_neighbors=1` is not going to do much for you. The whole point of this algorithm is to define what category that a new data point belongs to based on the neighboring data. If you have `n_neighbors=1`, you're not generalizing enough to the entire potential solution space.

In the example below, you see that setting `n_neighbors=3` takes advantage of more of the surrounding data to determine the class of the new data point. `n_neighbors` is considered a hyperparameter that needs to be optimized.

[image: knn]

image credit: https://towardsdatascience.com/knn-k-nearest-neighbors-1-a4707b24bd1d

Comment: hey thanks for your comment, but im still missing the answer, how can I display the output when running this line of code [  neigh.fit( X,y), ] by output I mean this line [  KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
           metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, n_neighbors=1, p=2,
           weights='uniform')]

Comment: I think you can see the parameters directly in your code (for the ones you specify) or in the documentation (default values)?

Comment: I would like to see the default ones for the KNeighbors classier, for my I only specified the K number but I would like to view the other parameters

Comment: in the docs you can see them. otherwise [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54572468/python-sklearn-get-list-of-available-hyper-parameters-for-model) should work

Comment: Thank you so much , this is what I wanted, somehow pycharm did not execute commands like the IDE book used